# How to debug reactjs from command line and attach it to chrome debugger

Tags: reactjs, debugging, chrome-debugging

I'm new to reactjs, I created a project using the `init` command, and run the sample using the `npm start` however I was wondering if there is a way to run it on debug mode and attach it to the chrome debugger. I have tried something like `node --inspect-brk=127.0.0.1:9229 .\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js start` however this just debugs the react-script.js file and I guess this is expected, but this is the only way I know to run a reactjs program.

NOTE: I have tried debugging with vscode however I'm interested on knowing what will be the procedure from command line.

Thanks in advance!